# How to add left border with image(s) dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need this type of page[image: desired output]

Which shows achievements of a particular individual on yearly basis, as you can see it is all dynamic, if there are tho achievements, two rows are shown and so on. I am able to produce this, [image: Current output].

*But I am not able to get these dots (or circles)*. I tried with `left-border` `border-image` and so on, but it would all break, *because* it is all dynamic, and any year can have as little as one achievement (or none, in that case it won't show up) or as many as tens (we don't have any max limit on this, but it can be many). So, if I do something with a image, it all breaks down.

Here's the page

```
  <div class="achievements-details-container">
    @foreach (var group in groupedModel)
    {
        <div class="achievements-details-group">
            @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
            {
                var item = group.ElementAt(i);

                <div class="achievements-details">
                    <div class="achievements-details-main">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                @(i == 0 ? item.Year.ToString() : string.Empty)
                            </div>
                            <div class="achievement-title-before">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 achievement-title">
                                @item.Title
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 smaller-padding-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/achievement_arrow.png")" alt="achievement_arrow" class="achievement-arrow-open" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                @item.SmallSummary
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 achievements-action-buttons no-padding">
                                <div class="">
                                    @{Html.RenderPartial("_EditDiv", item.StatusID == (int)VersionStatus.Draft);}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            }                   
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.achievements-details-container{

}
.achievements-details{

}
.achievements-details-main{

}
.achievement-title{
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.achievements-details-group
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.achievement-title-before:before 
/* This is the css that is giving me the border line, I don't know how to add css for that desired circle here */
/* I tried setting the content to something like '\2022' but it turned out terrible*/
/* I have that circle image as achievement_circle.png */
{
    content: '';
    border-right: 2px solid #EB5B1D;
    height: 500%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1%;
}
.achievements-details
{
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.achievements-action-buttons{

}
.no-padding 
{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.small-padding-left
{
    padding-left: 8%;
}
.smaller-padding-left
{
    padding-left: 4%;
}
.xx-small-padding-left
{
    padding-left: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to generate this using the :after pseudo element.

Something like:

```
.achievement-title-before:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  /*Set height and width*/
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;

  /*make it circular, as well as have a background color*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;

  /*position this accordingly*/
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Although, you may need to alter the positioning with the `left:` and `top:` values

Comment: What is this `tomato`?

Comment: Oh! Got it! It's a color.

Comment: Awesome man! It's working, though I had to change height and width to 12px to make it look as per my page.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the measurements quite right :P but I hope you can see how this is working

Comment: @jbutler483: Thanks, it did work, with a couple of modification in height and wight, and a margin-left: -5px to put it over the border line that was showing.

Comment: @Razort4x: instead of using a negaive margin-left, try setting 'left' to -5px (might be more acceptable since this is positioned absolutely)

Comment: @jbutler483: No, setting 'left'to -5px didn't work. It moved these circles to the extreme left, and the body has exact width of 980px, which is centralized, so.

Comment: @Razort4x: Ok I get you. Sounds like you've not set the achievement-title (i.e. parent) to position:relative. But in this case you should be able to get away with it :P